# Python assigning attribute changing length

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

I have a class that accepts a parameter X. This parameter X is a numpy array, containing lists that contain ints.

```
array([[  101,  2002,  8542, ...,     0,     0,     0],
   [  101,  2002,  8974, ...,     0,     0,     0],
   [  101,  5076,  2743, ...,     0,     0,     0],
   ...,
   [  101,  4302,  2253, ...,     0,     0,     0],
   [  101, 13875,  2003, ...,     0,     0,     0],
   [  101,  1045,  2031, ...,     0,     0,     0]])
```

I have a class that takes this X and assigns it to an attribute.

```
class TaskADataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, X, y):
    self.X = X,
    self.y = y
```

But the parameter X and the attribute X now have different lengths.

```
dataset = TaskADataset(X, y)
print(len(dataset.X), len(X))

1 10000
```

Why is this occurring?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: The Dataset it is inheriting is from torch.utils.data import Dataset

Comment: `self.X = X,` the extra comma turns it into a tuple with 1 element

Comment: You are an absolute hero! Genuinely can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [shriakhilc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6698642/shriakhilc) pointed out, I included a "," and this turned it into a tuple with one element.